# How to emit data from parent to child component [Angular 2]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

From parent component I do like this:

```
import {Observable, Subscription, Subject} from 'rxjs';

filteredBanks: Subject<any> = new Subject();
cilickFun() {
 this.filteredBanks.next('some value');
}
```

And child component:

```
@Input() filteredBanks: Subject<any>;

ngOnInit() {

        this.filteredBanks.subscribe(event => {
            console.log(event);
        });

}
```

I get error in console:
`Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT**

parent template:

```
<a (click)="cilickFun()"> EMIT</a>

<div class="col-md-9">
      <app-singlebank></app-singlebank>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add template of your parent component?

Comment: Added... But I think it is not problem with template

Comment: I don't see `[filteredBanks]="filteredBanks"`

Comment: Or maybe I should add something on `<app-singlebank></app-singlebank>`?

Comment: Yeah, my bad thanks!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0):

In your parent template it should be

```
<a (click)="cilickFun()"> EMIT</a>

<div class="col-md-9">
      <app-singlebank [filteredBanks]='filteredBanks'></app-singlebank>
</div>
```

I assume that app-singlebank is the selector for child component